# error with the loading files in scikit

Tags: scikit-learn

I am new to scikit-learn and tried to follow the tutorial on the site :
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

I downloaded the dataset, and used the load_files to load it but I keep getting error about the encoding. Below is how it is loaded :

```
twenty_train = load_files("./dataSet/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-train", description= None, categories=categories, load_content = True, encoding='utf-8', decode_error='strict', shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

But when I run the code, I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 30046:invalid start byte
```

Any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. To fix, this specify 'latin1' as the encoding when you run load_files, as in:

```
twenty_train = load_files("./dataSet/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-train", 
                           description= None, categories=categories, load_content = True, 
                           encoding='latin1', decode_error='strict', shuffle=True, 
                           random_state=42)
```

Comment: I removed categories=categories to make it work. *Think* it just infers categories from the folder names??

Comment: If anyone wants to learn about the other encoding options available in Python then check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is not the command that appears in the tutorial you linked. The one used in the tutorial is

`twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)`

The code you are using appears to be forcing a conversion to utf-8 from a dataset that is formatted as unicode, so you get the error.

Do you just want the tutorial to work, o do you need help loading the data as utf-8?

Comment: I downloaded the 20newsgroup from the original link given on the scikit tutorial site and tried to load it using the load_files method. I am using the tutorial except I don't want to use the fetch_20newsgroup() method. I want to use the load_files(). So, yes I need help loading the data as utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that the encoding of the dataset is latin1, not utf8.